# Get spusercontext like _spPageContextInfo on page load

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

Is there any way to get the Current user details once the page loads in SharePoint 2013 like we get data for

```
_spPageContextInfo
```

I don't like to call below methods again and again

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
```

and fetch the user assets

Comment: Why not just make a javascript library which has a function that does that for you? Then you just have to call that function and you get what you want.

Comment: the problem is angular is executing faster than waiting for SPUserContext to complete. because of this I'm getting null values in my application.

Comment: You may like to use JQuery deferreds/promises to make sure that you get the value

Comment: By the time JQuery promise completes page will be blank...